Why "the origin is outside of the top-level site" dont appear when loading iframe from cross-origin
I've https://staging-manabie.lightning.force.com/ that loads domain from backoffice.*
As expect it should show something like the origin is outside of the top-level site
As below screenshot 
But actually it dont 
Does anyone have experience at this, could you please help me figure out?
Expect: Below message should be show? Or does any configuration happen?
the origin is outside of the top-level site

